# Strange problem with SVN commit (can't commit file with *.conf* extension)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

When commiting file web.config I got this error:
svn: E195023: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E195023: Changing file 'C:\project\bin\web.config' is forbidden by the server
svn: E175013: Access to '/svn/project/trunk/bin/web.config' forbidden

Server is VisualSVN 4.1.3 Community Edition on Windows. Repository has one user and no groups (svn auth is enabled), commiting with TortoiseSVN 1.9.4

I can commit any other files to this Repository (to this folder and to another).
I tried to create test.config file, and it is also forbidden, same for web.conf and test.conf, looks like it is forbidden by mask *.conf*
I checked everything that I could, httpd.conf for VisualSVN server, ignore pattern in TortoiseSVN, I even tried to disable antiviral software.
There is also IIS on this machine, but VisualSVN server http server is on another port and not using IIS.

What else can I check to resolve this issue?

Comment: Any `*.conf*` file in any location? Try to commit this file using ``file:///` protocol

Comment: You mean svn protocol? I think Community Edition of VisualSVN supports only http/https.

Comment: Нет, Юра. Plain **local access** without *any* server with `file:///path/to/repo/on/FS` in order to exclude correlation to server's settings

Comment: I was able to add file with this command: C:\project\bin>svn import -m "test" web.config file:///C:/Repositories/project/trunk/bin/web.config --force-log. This means that problem in http server, but what problem could it be?

Comment: It turns out that SVN was using external IP to commit (URL is is bound to external IP). Application firewall is blocking some file extension, after switching to internal IP instead of URL problems is gone. So it was not related to SVN Server, Thank you everyone for answering.